# Variable Definitions and Random Numbers

Tags: matrix, random, variable-definitions, code-review, broken-code

I have currently created the following matrix:

```
m={{RandomReal[{0,1}],RandomReal[{0,1}]},{RandomReal[{0,1}],RandomReal[{0,1}]}}
```

In other words, a $2 \times 2$ matrix where the entries are real numbers. However, when I try to set $m$ to be a variable (to use it later to compute, say eigenvalues or eigenvectors), when I type `m` again, I obtain a different matrix than the one first obtained. I'm guessing that this is due to the fact that typing `m` will compute the matrix with other random reals. However, is there a way to store the matrix that is first obtained?

Say if `m` outputs the matrix `{{1,2},{3,4}}`, how can I fix this matrix for later use without obtaining a new one? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use `Set` (`m =`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`m :=`) the matrix will not be given new values unless you reevaluate the definition of m.

```
SeedRandom[1];

Clear[m]

m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]
```

> {{0.817389, 0.11142}, {0.789526, 0.187803}}

```
m
```

> {{0.817389, 0.11142}, {0.789526, 0.187803}}

```
m
```

> {{0.817389, 0.11142}, {0.789526, 0.187803}}

`m` has a fixed value. Compare with

```
SeedRandom[1];

Clear[m]

m := RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]

m
```

> {{0.817389, 0.11142}, {0.789526, 0.187803}}

```
m
```

> {{0.241361, 0.0657388}, {0.542247, 0.231155}}

Comment: Thank you! Are the lines of code `SeedRandom[1]` and `Clear[m]` required? Or they are just for "cleaning" purposes?

Comment: They are not required. Using `SeedRandom` ensures that you can exactly repeat the same results if you reevaluate the notebook. This can help in troubleshooting with random numbers.